# adding sqlite database value to label in xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to make a Xamarin App and adding the sqlite database value to a label, but it only shows me the name of my app + ".Table". -> MyApp.Table

the method:

```
public async Task<string> GetSAsync(int id)
    {    
        var s= await database.QueryAsync<Table>("SELECT Sign FROM Table WHERE ID = ?",id);
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s);
    }
```

the content page where I call the method

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        lbl.Text = await App.Database.GetSAsync(5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueryAsync<T>` is returning a list of records, assuming that ID is a unique key/value in the table, you can use Linq's `FirstOrDefault` to take the first record, if it exists, and *conditionally* access the `Sign` field (column).

Something like:

```
string s = "Not Found";
var listOfTableRecords = await database.QueryAsync<Table>("SELECT Sign FROM Table WHERE ID = ?", id);
s = listOfTableRecords.FirstOrDefault()?.Sign;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I figured I  can also make a foreach loop, but your solution is way shorter, I appreciate it.